# Complex architecture for simple application

Tags: architecture, soa, portal

As a consultant, I am responsible for designing the architecture of an application for an external company. The requirements for this application are rather simple and the whole thing could easily be solved with a basic web application, one or two incoming web services and a few outgoing document channels.

Things get more complicated because of two non-functional requirements:

1. Said company mandates that all internal applications be offered through an enterprise portal (for UI, security and technical uniformity)
2. Said company mandates that all applications be built using SOA principles so that services may be eventually published on an ESB and reused.

Architecture can be adapted to the portal requirement easily. Presentation will be built using portlets and integrate within the portal theme, and portal security will be reused. No big deal.

The SOA requirement is another story. Reusable services have not yet been identified. The way I see it, there are a few options:

1. Business logic is deployed on the portal and co-located with the presentation layer. No services are exposed and this decision is deferred.
2. Business logic is deployed on a separate server. An API is designed and all services are exposed using a closed protocol (e.g. RMI or Hessian). For services that need to be eventually reused, a SOAP API may be added on top of these services.
3. Business logic is deployed on a separate server. A SOAP API is designed and all services are exposed using this mechanism.

I want to avoid building something too complicated. I have lived through projects with business delegates, remote facades and DTOs where every single change required modifying several layers. Yet, it feels as if this SOA requirement forcibly pushes me in that direction.

**Update**: The more I think about it, the more I realize that complexity arises from the need to design a remoting API. Of course this requires creating interfaces for services, but what about the exchanged entities? Either I go the DTO way and end up with two parallels object hierarchies (one for DTOs and one for the actual entities) or I go the interface way and declare interfaces for all entities that need to transit across servers. Either way, this brings up a whole new set of problems and we will end up writing lots of boiler-plate code. And I thought we were through with that era...

What would be the best (or least worse) way to design this?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad to see that you have some real-world experience in building enterprise architectures and understand the consequences of different architecture. I've seen to many consultants that had just read a book about some new fashionable technology...

Option 1 is certainly the most pragmatic and the most affordable. You'd build an application that is needed now and don't invest into services that might or might not be used in the future. But as I understand it from your descriptions, this could be difficult to sell to the customer.

If you have to go with a distributed architecture (option 2 or 3), I'd still try to put as much as possible on the portal server. To this end, the term *business logic* has to be defined in a very narrow way. Everything that is even remotely related to the presentation (user settings, structuring of data for presentation purposes, already produced reports etc.) is declared *presentation logic* so it can be implemented on the portal server. So even if you cannot avoid the duplication and complexity that come with remoting, you can limit it to fewer areas. (Depending on the problem at hand, you could end up with a database on the portal server and a database on the business logic server that were better merged into one because there are so many data references between them. Hopefully, this is not the case here.)

Writing a reusable service with just a single application in mind is a wasted investment according to my experience. The servcie interface will become more complicated for this single application, part of the interface will never be used and hardly tested (because it was built for some imagined future application) and when the second application finally arrives one realizes that it has rather different requirements than foreseen. So the service will need to be redesigned and the already existing application to be modified. So don't start building services unless you have at least two (better three) applications that exist or in the process of being implemented. It pays off in terms of money and qualitiy of the service interface.

This advice isn't very specific but so is your description of the application's business requirements. You probably cannot give more information due to a confidentiality agreement you have signed. But I often found that business requirements help to argue for or against an option. E.g. the requirements, the related data, the data ownership and the involved processes can possibly better delimit the systems then technical considerations.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with option one, **marking** carefully services that create interface to the business layer and **forbidding** to call anything behind this interface from the presentation layer. This enables you to make the switch to the options with remoting (regardless if you choose number two or three) later with reasonably low and predictable cost.

If this is not possible, the option two promises more effective use of resources.

One fun part when dividing presentation an business logic was not mentioned yet - this is when you have to filter data coming from business logic based on data existing only in presentation layer, e.g. user and his/her permission. :)